# Use javascript in a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a script that a user can input a value from 1 to 10 and then have the result displayed on a radar graph.

[I have a demo of the it working HERE on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpAGu)
Some of the JS:

```
var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["OPTION - 1", "OPTION - 2", "OPTION - 3", "OPTION - 4", "OPTION - 5", "OPTION - 6", "OPTION - 7", "OPTION - 8", "OPTION - 9", "OPTION - 10", "OPTION - 11", "OPTION - 12"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Wheel Of Life",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            data: [10,10,10,10,10,10,10, 10, 10, 10,10, 10]
        }

    ]
};

//This is the function that renders the chart for the first time
    window.onload = function(){
    window.myRadarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });


}

 //For Every Change of value this is the function that renders the chart. All the actions have to be attached to this function. That should be pretty much it. 
    function runSubmitFunction() {
    //myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[0].value = 
    var datalist = document.getElementById ("browsers");
myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[0].value = document.getElementById ("data1").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[1].value = document.getElementById ("data2").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[2].value = document.getElementById ("data3").value;
myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[3].value = document.getElementById ("data4").value;
  myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[4].value = document.getElementById ("data5").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[5].value = document.getElementById ("data6").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[6].value = document.getElementById ("data7").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[7].value = document.getElementById ("data8").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[8].value = document.getElementById ("data9").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[9].value = document.getElementById ("data10").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[10].value = document.getElementById ("data11").value;
    myRadarChart.datasets[0].points[11].value = document.getElementById ("data12").value;
    myRadarChart.update();
     }
```

I have tried quite a few thing in wordpress but can't get it to work (Referenced chart.js in header.php, numerous varieties of posting the code from demo.html into a wordpress page etc).

Answer (score 0):

you must have to include your chart.js file in head section of wordpress main page by using below function.You must want to write this function in your function.php file so that it include this chart.js file in your main page header so to get accessed from every where .

```
function wps_poll_options_page () {

 wp_enqueue_script(
        'getChart', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/chart.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put your code into function.php and put chart.js in /js/chart.js, then added the heml to the wordpress page but it didn't work. Not sure why it's not ..

Comment: @user3581315 please try to view the page source so that you may come to know weather js file included or not.